# Windows toast notification action

Tags: windows, uwp

Is it possible to create button action on Windows notification toast that would not dismiss the notification from action center when clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see the [Toast with pending update documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/toast-pending-update).